I am trying to make a folder#1 inside of folder#2 then i want to send a pdf to folder#1 (this child of 1) Apps Script
function convertToPDF() {
  
    var documentId = "1IeY_KXhhdUbPcLIi1WL_nd8AUky5eLDk48Ql1sW6sII"; 
    var document = DocumentApp.openById(documentId); 
    //refreshDocumentContent(document);
    //document
  
    var dynamicId = "12XPDcrng6nZ7ibGziAwNT8eaZ7DYHDoXy3OnknWzyAI"
    let cell = "B17";
    //var sheetName = "sheet1";
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dynamicId);
    var offerName = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue();

    var blob = document.getAs('application/pdf');
    // Set the name of the PDF file
    var pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob).setName(offerName + "_offer" + ".pdf"); 

    //var finalFolder = "17bvQ3LkYPd1Es68G0HsoAgRXijSBGdKw";
    var folderName = offerName + "_offer";
    var newFolder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
    newFolder.moveTo("17bvQ3LkYPd1Es68G0HsoAgRXijSBGdKw");
    pdfFile.moveTo(newFolder);
    
    Logger.log(offerName);
}

Here is the error I get.

Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature
for DriveApp.Folder.moveTo.

This code works if i dont involde the parent folder and just send to pdf to a new folder, I am wondering why i cant make a folder in the parent folder and then send the pdf to the child folder.
Your feedback is greatly appreciated

Modification point:

The argument of moveTo(destination) of Class Folder is the object of Class Folder DriveApp.Folder. But, in your script, you use the string value as the argument like newFolder.moveTo("17bvQ3LkYPd1Es68G0HsoAgRXijSBGdKw");. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.

When this point is reflected in your showing script, please modify it as follows.
From:
newFolder.moveTo("17bvQ3LkYPd1Es68G0HsoAgRXijSBGdKw");

To:
newFolder.moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById("17bvQ3LkYPd1Es68G0HsoAgRXijSBGdKw"));

I think that with this modification, your current error Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DriveApp.Folder.moveTo. will be removed.
Reference:

moveTo(destination) of Class Folder

